# Extraneous text after `else' directive

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

First

I reference gnu make manual 3.81, because my version is 3.81 (make --v)

section 7.2

```
conditional-directive
text-if-one-is-true
else conditional-directive
text-if-true
else
text-if-false
endif
```

so my makefile

```
  version=ag101p


  ifeq ($(version),ag101p)
  ag101p:ag101p.o zigbee.o
    cc -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^
  else ifeq($(version),test)
    @echo "test"
  else
  CFLAGS += -DM2C
  m2c:m2c.o zigbee.o
    cc -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^
  endif

  .PHONY:clean
  clean:CLL
    rm -rf *.o ag101p m2c
  CLL:
```

but console display

**Makefile:7: Extraneous text after `else' directive**

Comment: else ifeq($(version),test)

modify

else ifeq ($(version),test)

lack SPACE

Comment: This isn't your problem, but in case anyone else looking for this error happens upon it, I had a shell continuation (`;\`) on the line before `ifeq`, and removing it solved this error.

Comment: Well that's some annoying syntax highlighting.

Comment: Also not your problem, but the same not-so-helpful error message also comes up for unbalanced parentheses in the `else ifeq (...)` expression.

Answer (score 7):

By adding a space between "else ifeq" and "(" works on linux platform. But on windows it won't work. I fix this on windows by adding anther endif make the  "if else" nested.

```
ifeq ($(version),ag101p)
  ag101p:ag101p.o zigbee.o
    cc -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^
else
ifeq ($(version),test)
    @echo "test"
else
  CFLAGS += -DM2C
  m2c:m2c.o zigbee.o
    cc -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $^
endif
endif

  .PHONY:clean
  clean:CLL
    rm -rf *.o ag101p m2c
  CLL:
```

Comment: I faced the same problem on linux platform with make utiliy version 3.80.The above suggested changes worked.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue. Solution: Install GNU version of make with Cygwin installer.